# Hangups [github] failed login attempt

Tags: python, google-app-engine, github

I'm trying to login to my google account using hangups.
Yet I'm getting the following error:

```
Login Failed (Unknown verification code input)
```

I know the password is correct since when I input an invalid password I get:

```
Login Failed (Authorization code cookie not found)
```

Please help! I tried generating an app password, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after using google in the **appropriate** way.
https://github.com/tdryer/hangups/issues/350#issuecomment-323553771